# Find top 10 players - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ranking, leaderboard

I have a codescore table which will soon cross 500,000 rows of dummy data. The table is used to hold the points scored by players in a game. Following are the columns present in the table.

```
questionid bigint,
playerid varchar(20),
playerscore float,
questionlevel enum('EASY', 'MODERATE', 'HARD'),
questionstatus enum('PENDING','SOLVED'),
lastmodified datetime,
created datetime
Primary key (questionid, playerid)
```

Sample data:

```
+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
| questionid | playerid | playerscore | questionstatus |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
| 1          | 1        | 5           | PENDING        |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
| 1          | 2        | 10          | SOLVED         |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
| 3          | 1        | 10          | SOLVED         |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
| 2          | 3        | 10          | SOLVED         |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
```

Each questionid has some points associated with it and when a player solves the problem correctly he is awarded the points and an entry in made in the codescore table and the questionstatus for that entry is set to SOLVED. If the player has partially solved a problem then some part of the total points is awarded to the player and an entry is made in the table with questionstatus set to PENDING.

A player can solve a given problem any number of times as long as the status is PENDING, to improve his score. Once the status is changed to SOLVED then no more score update is done. Though the player is still allowed to  solve the problem for practicing.

Now the main part of the problem:
Find top 10 players (order by score in decreasing order) for each questionlevel (EASY, MODERATE, HARD)

Using the following query to find top 10 players for the HARD level:

```
SELECT playerid, SUM(playerscore) AS score FROM codescore
WHERE questionlevel = 'HARD'
GROUP BY playerid
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Is the above query going to work well if the records in the table crosses 500K or 1 Million rows in production environment?
Is there any better solution for this type of problem or a better query that can be used to accomplish this task?

[Backend: using MySQL and CodeIgniter]

Comment: Your query seems fine

Comment: Why do you `SUM(playerscore)`? There is no `GROUP BY`. Other than that the query looks fine. Performance might not instant but it is a lot of data afterall. MySQL is pretty good at dealing with large datasets, worry about performance when it's actually a problem.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: One perfomance improvement would come from adding an index to the table based on Playerid, QuestionLevel

Comment: Your query is fine (and does have a GROUP BY clause). However the indexes you have will be critically important to the performance of the query. Do you have an index covering both the questionlevel and the playerid fields (ie, one index that covers both fields, NOT one index on each field).

Comment: A player will be solving too many questions so I have to find the total score thats why I used SUM(playerscore) and then I did group by playerid

Comment: @Kickstart yes I have indexed questionid, playerid, questionlevel and questionstatus. So, when the player revisits a question that he earlier attempted, he will be informed of the question status (PENDING/SOLVED)

Comment: Another improvement, if you run into performance issues would be to create a "totals" ("balances", "summary") table that would be maintained by insert / update / delete triggers on your detail table. The table would simply have columns for PlayerId, QuestionLevel, TotalScore. You'd probably want a stored proc that resets the balances for one player or all players, and then call it from the trigger with playerid, and run it nightly for all players (to ensure integrity). This highlights the frequent trade-off between storage and speed.

Comment: @yusufshakeel - Are those 4 indexes, one on each of the 4 different columns? Or 1 index covering those 4 columns? And if one index on 4 colulmns, in what order are they in the index? MySQL will only use 1 index on a table in a piece of SQL, and to be effective your query needs an index on questionlevel and playerid (in that order).

Comment: @C.List I think a separate table for total score, updated daily for player ranking is a good option. This way the load of recalculating the ranking can be reduced. And each day players will get their latest updated ranking.

Comment: @Kickstart The table has separate indexing on the 4 columns. Index ordering: questionlevel, playerid, questionid, questionstatus. Do you think the current ordering need some change?

Comment: If you have separate indexes then the ordering is irrelevant. MySQL would only use 1 of those indexes in any query, and the order that separate indexes are declared is effectively irrelevant. But the order of columns within 1 index (ie, when you have one index that covers multiple columns) is VERY important. Try executing the following on the table _ALTER TABLE codescore ADD INDEX codescore_index (questionlevel, playerid);_

Comment: @Kickstart I will add the new index and check. Thanks

Comment: @Kickstart thanks, I made the update in the code and index its working fine. hope it will be in ok state when i put it on production.

Comment: @C.List thanks, I created a separate table for ranking. Running cron to update that table every 12 hours.